# InvalidParameterError when fitting Random Forest Model in Python

Tags: python-3.x, random-forest

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=25)

cv_params = {'max_depth': [2,4,6,None],
             'min_samples_leaf': [1,2],
             'min_samples_split': [2,3],
             'max_features': [2,3,4],
             'n_estimators': [75, 100, 125, 150]
            }
scoring = {'accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1'}

rf_cv = GridSearchCV(rf, cv_params, scoring=scoring, cv=5, refit='recall')

rf_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

For the code above, I got an error when trying to fit the model. I can't figure out what the issue is but the error says "InvalidParameterError: The 'scoring' parameter of GridSearchCV must be a str among {'f1', 'neg_root_mean_squared_error',etc..}

My scoring parameters fit within the criteria the error mentions and thus I stumped by what the problem is.

I checked the spelling of the scoring metrics and made sure they were all spelled correctly. The result threw the same error message.

Comment: It would be nice to share the complete code and Traceback. I have tried your implementation and it works for me with Python3.11.

Answer (score 0):

When `{}` is used to define a set i.e `The scoring must be {'f1', 'neg_root_mean_squared_error',etc..}` it means `the scoring must be from the set  {'f1', 'neg_root_mean_squared_error'}` and not be a set, pr say.

You have given a set as scoring, but looking at the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) you can give *either* "str, callable, list, tuple or dict "

So, if you want to use e.g the `f1-score` you have to set `scoring="f1"`.

Or if you want to use multiple scores i.e using 'accuracy', 'precision', 'recall' and 'f1' I assume you should just replace your set with a list i.e

`scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1']`